# Wing IDE Personal Edition Multilanguage Support

Tags: python, editor, utf, wing-ide

When I open a file which has multilanguage character contents arabic contents are not rendering correctly, I setup encoding to utf-8 but did not help.  How do you solve this?

Comment: Did you set a coding comment at the top of your source file?  Also check the Debugger > I/O > Encoding preferences if you haven't already.  It may also be that the font being used by default in the editor does not have the necessary glyphs.  You can change that with the User Interface > Fonts > Editor Font/Size preference.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions @Stephan but none work. How come VS Code displays every characters correctly bu not WIng.  Also how do you install extensions like emmet and others in WIng Personal 6.0?

Comment: VS may be guessing encodings correctly.  If you want further help with this, include the code and your settings, or just email those to support@wingware.com.  Assuming you mean emmet the web dev editor plugin:  There is no emmet support for Wing as far as I can tell.  It's a plugin that has to be adapted for each editor.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

On windows the process for getting code to display correctly includes **all** of:

- including a comment on the **second** line of each source file with `#coding:utf-8`, *the first should really be the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`*
- ensure that you have a font installed with good Unicode support, *including the character page that you are going to be using* - `Consolas` *(the default for Wing-IDE)* is **usually** a good choice but *AFAIK* does not include the full Arabic character ranges however `Lucida Console` should provide this.
- Ensure that Wing-IDE has the Edit->Preferences->User Interface->Fonts->Editor Font/Size set to the selected font, i.e. Licida Console.